# Selecting Content Within the TinyMCE Editor Using jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, tinymce

I have tried to find an answer to this problem on Stackoverflow and elsewhere, but none of the solutions I have found seem to work for me.  Here, then, is my problem:

I have a simple TinyMCE button that I have added in WordPress.  The button works as it should.  Now, I want to be able to select the content that the button enters into the editor using jQuery.  That is where I am having trouble.

Here is the code for the button:

```
(function() {
   tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.wpAddContent', {
      init : function(ed, url) {
         ed.addButton('wpaddcontent', {
            title : 'WP Add Content',
            image : url+'/addContentImage.png',
            onclick : function() {
                 ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '\
                    <div class="row">\
                        <div class="large-6 columns">Some content...</div>\
                        <div class="large-6 columns">Some content...div>\
                    </div>\
                ');
              }
          });
      },
    createControl : function(n, cm) {
      return null;
    },
    getInfo : function() {
      return {
        longname : "WP Add Content",
        author : '',
        authorurl : '',
        infourl : '',
        version : ""
      };
    }
  });
   tinymce.PluginManager.add('wpaddcontent', tinymce.plugins.wpAddContent);

})();
```

Now, what I want to know is simply how I could select the div with the class of row using jQuery.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Moshe

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it seems that I figured this out - there are a number of options from the TinyMCE API.  This is one of the ones that works:

```
  ed.onVisualAid.add(function(ed, e, s) {
       jQuery('#content_ifr').contents().find('.row')..css({'background-color', 'red');
  });
```

You can find other options here:  http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:class.tinymce.Editor